# Como puedo eliminar parte del stock de un producto con ArrayList Java

Tags: java, arraylist, java-ee

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de Java, en donde ahora tengo que agregar y eliminar stock, la parte de agregar stock al producto ya esta listo, sin embargo, cuando intento hacer la parte de eliminar stock no me muestra nada en la parte de la consola, no se si será por una de las clases que están creadas o por una línea de código, estoy confundido.

Esta es la prueba, y en donde me muestra el importe de los productos y la agregación de productos al stock, todos me muestran excepto la parte de salida, no entiendo porque.

```
package negocio;

import java.util.List;

public class Prueba {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Articulo art1=new Articulo("A001","Articulo 1",10,100);
    Articulo art2=new Articulo("A002","Articulo 2",20,200);
    Articulo art3=new Articulo("A003","Articulo 3",30,300);
 
    OrdenCompra ordCom=new OrdenCompra();
    ordCom.crearLineaCompra(art1, 2);
    ordCom.crearLineaCompra(art2, 2);
    ordCom.crearLineaCompra(art3, 2);
    
    NotaVenta notVen=new NotaVenta();
    notVen.crearLineaVenta(art1, 2);
    notVen.crearLineaVenta(art2, 2);
    notVen.crearLineaVenta(art3, 2);
    
    List cesta=ordCom.getCesta();
    System.out.println("Calculando Importe");
    for(int i=0;i<cesta.size();i++){
        LineaCompra lin=(LineaCompra)cesta.get(i);
        System.out.println(lin.getArt().getCod()+"  "+lin.getArt().getNom()+"  "+lin.getArt().getPre()+"   "+lin.getCan()+" "+lin.getArt().getSto());
    }
    System.out.println("============================");
    System.out.println("Entrada");
    Kardex kar=new Kardex();
    List lis=kar.getEntrada(ordCom);
    for(int i=0;i<lis.size();i++){
        Object[]f=(Object[])lis.get(i);
        System.out.println(f[0]+"  "+f[1]+"  "+f[2]+"  "+f[3]+"  "+f[4]);
    }
    
    System.out.println("============================");
    System.out.println("Salida");
    Kardex kar2=new Kardex();
    List lis2=kar2.getSalida(notVen);
    for(int i=0;i<lis2.size();i++){
        Object[]f2=(Object[])lis2.get(i);
        System.out.println(f2[0]+"  "+f2[1]+"  "+f2[2]+"  "+f2[3]+"  "+f2[4]);
    }
}
```

}

Esta es la Nota de Venta

```
package negocio;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class NotaVenta {
    private List cesta=new ArrayList();

    public void crearLineaVenta(Articulo art,int can){
        LineaVenta linVen=new LineaVenta(art,can);
        cesta.add(linVen);
    }

    public double getTotal(){
        double tot=0;
        for(int i=0;i<cesta.size();i++){
            LineaVenta lin=(LineaVenta)cesta.get(i);
            tot+=lin.getImporte();
        }
        return tot;
    }

    public List getCesta() {
        return cesta;
    }

}
```

Este, la línea de Venta
package negocio;

```
public class LineaVenta {
    private Articulo art;
    private int can;

    public LineaVenta() {
    }

    public LineaVenta(Articulo art, int can) {
        this.art = art;
        this.can = can;
    }

    public Articulo getArt() {
        return art;
    }

    public void setArt(Articulo art) {
        this.art = art;
    }

   public int getCan() {
        return can;
    }

    public void setCan(int can) {
        this.can = can;
    }
    public double getImporte(){
        return art.getPre()*can;
    }
}
```

Y este seria el kardex

```
package negocio;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Kardex {
    public List getEntrada(OrdenCompra com){
        List lis=new ArrayList();
        List cesta=com.getCesta();
        for(int i=0;i<cesta.size();i++){
            LineaCompra lin=(LineaCompra)cesta.get(i);
            Object[]fil=new Object[5];
            fil[0]=lin.getArt().getCod();
            fil[1]=lin.getArt().getNom();
            fil[2]=lin.getArt().getSto();
            fil[3]=lin.getCan();
            fil[4]=lin.getArt().getSto() + lin.getCan();
            lis.add(fil);
        }
        return lis;
    }

    public List getSalida(NotaVenta ven){
        List lis2=new ArrayList();
        List cesta=ven.getCesta();
        for(int i=0;i<cesta.size();i++){
            LineaVenta lint=(LineaVenta)cesta.get(i);
            Object[]fil=new Object[5];
            fil[0]=lint.getArt().getCod();
            fil[1]=lint.getArt().getNom();
            fil[2]=lint.getArt().getSto();
            fil[3]=lint.getCan();
            fil[4]=lint.getArt().getSto() + lint.getCan();
            lis2.remove(fil);
       }
       return lis2;
    }
}
```

Comment: veo que en tu clase Kardex vos en el metodo getEntrada usas una lista lis para agregar y en el metodo getSalida usas otra lista lis2 para eliminar ... no seria logico usar una sola lista ????

Comment: sii, lo he intentado pero no me aparece nada, estoy un poco desesperado, le he cambiado y dejado cosas como están pero no sigue apareciendo lo que busco.

Comment: Hola Juan, **List lis=new ArrayList();** debe ser declarado fuera de cualquier método, **lis2** no debe existir, aparte de eso, veo un problema conceptual, tanto cuando agregas un producto, como cuando lo quitas, debes verificar que el producto está en la lista, si está, modificas la cantidad, y en el caso de ser una compra, si no está lo agregas, osea, básicamente debes reescribir **getEntrada** y **getSalida**.